# AngularJS 1.x - $scope.data undefined in $watch even though $scope seems to be available

Tags: angularjs, scope, watch

I am watching $scope.taskId and then trying to access a property on $scope.data.

Here's my function:

```
$scope.$watch('taskId', function(value) {
    console.log('here---------------');
    console.log($scope, $scope.data);
    var titlePrefix = undefined;
    if (value) {
        titlePrefix = $scope.getTaskTitlePrefix();
        Page.setTitle(titlePrefix + $scope.taskId);
        $scope.loadData();
    }
});
```

I am logging $scope and $scope.data above in line 3.

**(console.log($scope, $scope.data);)**

Here's the output in the console:

> here---------------
>
> m {$$childTail: m, $$childHead: b, $$nextSibling: m, $$watchers: 
>   Array(81), $$listeners: Object…}
>
> undefined

Any ideas why $scope seems to be ready and available but its variables are not??

--------------------- edit 14.06.17 ----------------------

This is the HTML where the taskId variable is initialised and as you can see there is a whole lot going on here. This is a major Laravel and Angular application with more than 2700 pages without including vendor or node folders (1700+ Laravel, 1000+ angular)

```
<div ng-controller="TasksCtrl" ng-init="taskId = '{!! $task->id !!}'" ng-cloak>
    <span ng-init="severities = {{ json_encode($severities) }}"></span>
    <span ng-init="statuses = {{ $statuses }}"></span>
    <span ng-init="users = {{ $users }}"></span>
    <span ng-init="subtypes = {{ App\Modules\Bookings\TaskSubtype::support()->get() }}"></span>
    <span ng-init="standard_prices = {{ StandardPrice::all() }}"></span>
    <span ng-init="shelf_types = {{ json_encode(App\Modules\Bookings\Task::getShelfTypes()) }}"></span>
```

That is an excerpt from tasks.blade.php file which is content of the page.

The actual title is used in layouts.blade.php and it actually sets the title of the browser tab and **NOT** the title of any "on page" heading.

```
(head)

(meta charset="utf-8")
(meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1")

<title ng-controller="TitleController" ng-cloak>{[{ Page.getTitle() }]}</title>
```

(I've had to use parentheses () instead of < > because Stack's markdown doesn't allow >head< or >meta< tags for obvious reasons.)

This the getTitle function if it helps.

```
archDB.factory('Page', function () {
    var title = 'Seraph';
    return {
        getTitle: function() { return title; },
        setTitle: function(newTitle) { title = newTitle; }
    };
});
```

And here's the $scope.data variable inspection from the browser js console
to give a sense of scale.

data: m
$promise
:
d
$resolved
:
true
alarm_date
:
null
antivirus_state
:
null
assigned_to
:
104
attended_time
:
0
auto_booked
:
1
booking_fee
:
null
booking_fee_id
:
null
builds
:
Array(0)
cancelled_reason
:
null
client
:
Object
client_id
:
53
client_type
:
"client"
collected_at
:
null
completed
:
0
completed_at
:
null
created_at
:
"2016-12-07 11:23:03"
created_by
:
16
creator
:
Object
customer_notifications
:
Array(0)
deleted_at
:
null
delivered
:
0
delivered_by
:
null
devices
:
Array(0)
direct_dial
:
null
due_date
:
null
exchange_id
:
null
feedback
:
null
followup_id
:
null
formatedAttendedTime
:
""
formatedUnattendedTime
:
""
id
:
84222
invoice_number
:
null
invoiced
:
0
invoiced_at
:
null
invoiced_by_project
:
0
labour
:
0
modifier
:
Object
needs_calling
:
0
needs_delivery
:
null
no_price_reason
:
null
nopassword_reason
:
null
onsite_end
:
"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
onsite_start
:
"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
order_task_id
:
null
paid
:
0
paid_at
:
"2016-12-07"
parts
:
Array(0)
parts_total
:
0
passed_qa
:
null
passwords
:
Array(0)
pin
:
null
points
:
0
prebook
:
0
prebook_date
:
"01-01-1970"
problem
:
" **removed**"
project_id
:
null
qa_id
:
null
qa_tasks
:
Array(0)
related_tasks
:
Array(0)
return_id
:
null
revision_history
:
Array(0)
satisfied_client
:
null
seraph_id
:
null
severity_id
:
2
shelf
:
null
shelf_type
:
null
site
:
Object
site_id
:
53
site_user
:
Object
site_user_id
:
535
standard_price
:
null
standard_price_id
:
null
status
:
Object
status_id
:
1
subscribed_user
:
Array(0)
subscribers
:
Array(0)
subtype_id
:
1
template_items
:
Array(0)
templates
:
Array(0)
time_spent
:
0
title
:
"For Nadeem"
type
:
"support"
unattended_time
:
0
updated_at
:
"2016-12-07 11:24:04"
updated_by
:
94
user
:
Object

Comment: $scope.data is undefined, where do you set it?

Comment: Are you setting data value in HTML? can you please update HTML code

Comment: The controller has around 4 or 5 five other $watches and some 20 other functions which can access $scope variables but we're stumped why when we log $scope we can explore it in the console and when we get to the $scope.data object we can even explore that but when we try logging $scope.data as above it shows as undefined. It is not being passed to the front end so ng-model doesn't come in to play here. $scope is ready but $scope.data is undefined  $scope.data in this controller contains approx 40 separate properties so it and $scope has around 10 other variables.

Comment: @Thomas Can you take a look at my edited post, thanks

Comment: Your question went out of scope. There is too much code / information. Try isolating your problem to a narrow scope. Chances are that you will find your answer without asking further questions on the way.

I think your problem is related to the angular scope inheritance

Answer (score 0):

both of the scope and scope variables are ready. the reason you get `undefined` is you need to initialize and assign value to the scope variable first. otherwise, it will show as undefined.

```
$scope.data = "whatever";

$scope.$watch('taskId', function(value) {
    console.log('here---------------');
    console.log($scope, $scope.data);
    var titlePrefix = undefined;
    if (value) {
        titlePrefix = $scope.getTaskTitlePrefix();
        Page.setTitle(titlePrefix + $scope.taskId);
        $scope.loadData();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope belongs to controller and don't use more watchers, not good practice. You can assign variables in HTML as follows

```
<input ng-model="data">
```

or in controller

```
$scope.data = "AngularJS 4.0 is out. Enjoy.";
```

We can use once assigned values to scope any where in view and controller.